# Select and option values

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few selects in my code, but they all have the same options:

```
<select id ="pais">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
        <option value="E">E</option>
        <option value="F">F</option>
        <option value="G">G</option>
        <option value="H">H</option>
    </select>
    Localidade
    <select id ="localidade">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
        <option value="E">E</option>
        <option value="F">F</option>
        <option value="G">G</option>
        <option value="H">H</option>
    </select>
    Morada
    <select id ="morada">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
        <option value="E">E</option>
        <option value="F">F</option>
        <option value="G">G</option>
        <option value="H">H</option>
    </select>
```

Is there any simple why for me to not repeat the values every single time? like define one time and use them for all the other selects id?

I'm using javascript besides html by the way.

Comment: You could use a string to hold the options and pass then during the pageload event

Comment: It depends. Are the selects pure HTML or created dynamically? If it is pure HTML you could just leave it. It is possible to create it with JavaScript, but that isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: Just a warning, if you change from pure html to javascript, you will have a performance cost and you will also make your site less accessible as your options will no longer work if the user has js turned off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this function to fill my selects:

```
function fillSelect(element, dataList){
    element = (typeof element === 'string' ? document.getElementById(element) : element);

    for (var i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++) {
        element.options[element.length] = new Option(dataList[i].Value, dataList[i].Key);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var selectData = [{Key:'A',Value:'A'},{Key:'B',Value:'B'},{Key:'C',Value:'C'}];
fillSelect('pais',selectData);
fillSelect('localidade',selectData);
```

Answer (score 1):

quick and easy:
first empty your forms, just define them like that:

`<select id ="morada"></select>`

, same for the other ones, then :

```
var optionArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
var strOut ="";
for(var i=0; i<optionArray.length;i++){
   strOut += '<option value=" ' + optionArray[i] + ' "> ' + optionArray[i] + '</option>';
}
$("#pais").html(strOut);
$("#morada").html(strOut);
$("#localidades").html(strOut);
```

EDIt: well it seems that A1rPun gave a better answer than  me;)

Answer (score 0):

make a array of value that is repeating and run a for loop inside select statement and assign value to value attribute of option tag through array value.

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

<select id="demo1">
</select>

<select id="demo2">
</select>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var select1 = document.getElementById("demo1");  
    var select2 = document.getElementById("demo2"); 
    var i=0;
    var val= ["A","B","C","D"];
    for(i=0;i<val.length ;i++){  
     select1.options[select1.options.length] = new Option(val[i],val[i]);  
     select2.options[select2.options.length] = new Option(val[i],val[i]);  

} 
}
</script>
</body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looped through the select elements to populate them. Have the static data defined in the function that adds each option element.

EDIT: Using the 'new Option' construct as A1rPun used, is a much better option than the createElement used here.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt4S8/)

```
var selects = ["localidade", "pais"];
var selectLength = selects.length;
for(var s = 0; s < selectLength; s++) {
    addOptions(selects[s]);
}

function addOptions(selectName){
    var selectData = [{Key:'A',Value:'A'},{Key:'B',Value:'B'},{Key:'C',Value:'C'}];
    var sel = document.getElementById(selectName);
    if (sel != undefined) {
        var arrayLength = selectData.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.text = selectData[i].Key;
            opt.value = selectData[i].Value;
            sel.add(opt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, if you elaborate on the problems, perhaps I can fix them?

Comment: You have static data in your function whereas I had it outside the function because the data may come from anywhere. The `addOption` can be rewritten in 3 lines of code. I did learn something because I didn't know about `add` function.

Comment: The question did mention static data as the source data for the selects. Agree with you on rather using 'Option' than 'createElement'. Learnt something there. As for verboseness, bit harsh to get a downvote but ok.

Answer (score 0):

The following produces a numbered option select, within a table. 
@AirPun's answer is a more modern approach.

```
<tr>
    <td align="center" id="tableShow"></td> 
</tr>

function tableNumbers() {
    var i = 0;
    var selectText = "";
    selectText += '<select  name="tableNums" id="tableNum" size="1" onChange="storeTable()">' + "\n";
    for (i = 0; i<=20 ; i++) {
        selectText += "<option value="+'"'+i+'"'+">"+i+"</option>" + "\n";
        }
    selectText += "</select>";
    document.getElementById('tableShow').innerHTML = selectText;

}
```