# Dynamically generated select option dropdown menu using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

This is the select menu I am going to create. But as you can see there are static data. As I actually have bunch of JSON data passed from backend servlet, so there will be hundreds of items for options. I want something like dynamically generate option menu for my dropdown box.

```
<select id="brand-select" name="brand">
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    <option value="lexus">Lexus</option>
</select>
```

This is my tryout and it doesn't work:

HTML:

```
<select id="brand-select" name="brand" onChange="createOptions">
    <option value="none"></option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
//Asssume I have jsonDataForBrands ready, and it contains 100s items
function createOptions() {
    for (var fieldIndex in jsonDataForBrands) {
        html += '<option value=' + fieldIndex  + '>' + jsonDataForBrands[field].title + '</option>';
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the structure of the json ?

Comment: please ignore json stuff for now, because i have already extracted all data,   jsonDataForBrands[1].title = bmw   jsonDataForBrands[2].title=VW   jsonDataForBrands[3].title=Benz  .. etc.. i just need this branddata populated to 'optionmenu' for dropdown box, cheers

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365889/select-and-option-values/23366031#23366031) answer fit your needs?

Comment: not really...i dont think it s the same type of question.. my things are actually quite simple...in one word... i need a function() to create 100s options for my select drop down box...and the data are all there already in jsonDataForBrands[1].title  ,jsonDataForBrands[2].title,  jsonDataForBrands[3].title....etc...

Comment: so are these jsons stored in an array..? You need to provide more info about the structure of data you have..

Comment: leave the json...think its a a arraylist, so there will be something like this  [bmw, audi, benz....]  100s of item in there... now i need 100s of this item populate on option for dropdown select....

Comment: @seph there's no `ArrayList` in javascript.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out by myself...

HTML:

```
<select id="brand-select" name="brand">
                </select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function creatBrandOptions(){
    for (var field in jsonDataForBrands) {
         $('<option value="'+ jsonDataForBrands[field].name +'">' + jsonDataForBrands[field].title + '</option>').appendTo('#brand-select');
    }
}
```

I did an Ajax call to retrieve JSON data from my servlet and then creatBrandOptions() in the same function BTW...

Answer (score 1):

You beat me to it. Here's a complete simplified example of adding options to a select using jquery:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="populateMenu" >Populate menu</button>

<select id="mySelect">


</select>

<script>
    var optionValues= [[1,"first"],[2,"second"]];

    jQuery("#populateMenu").click( function () {
        for (var i=0;i<optionValues.length;i++){
            jQuery('#mySelect').append(jQuery("<option></option>").val(optionValues[i][0]).text(optionValues[i][1]))
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this to avoid population on the menu with previous option when user changes option add below before your FOR statement 


                             var $select = $('#mySelect'); 
    $select.find('option').remove();

Answer (score 0):

This example uses jQuery. See if it suits you:

```
function createOptions( jsonDataForBrands ) {
   $('#brand-select option').remove(); // first remove all options
   for (var i=0; i<jsonDataForBrands.length; i++)

   for (var fieldIndex in jsonDataForBrands) { // then populatem them
      $('#brand-select').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", fieldIndex  ).text(jsonDataForBrands[field].title) );
}
```